# log4j2 Not Creating RollingFile Logs

Tags: tomcat, slf4j, log4j2

I have just started using log4j2 with slf4j2 but I'm facing a problem where I'm trying to create rolling log files on daily basis. I am able to create an active log file but when I change the system date by one day, logging happens on the same active file which I thought it should have archived previous days' logs to another file.

Following is the log4j2.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR" monitorInterval="5">
 <Properties>
  <Property name="log-path">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Appenders>
  <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
   <PatternLayout
    pattern="%d{dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
  </Console>
  <RollingFile name="file-gen" fileName="${log-path}/demopro.log"
   filePattern="${log-path}/%d{yyyy-MM}/demopro-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.gz">
   <PatternLayout
    pattern="%d{dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
   <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
   </Policies>
  </RollingFile>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
  <Root level="info">
   <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  </Root>
  <Logger name="org.hkb.tryone" level="debug" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  </Logger>
  <Logger name="org.hkb.trytwo" level="info" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
   <AppenderRef ref="file-gen" />
  </Logger>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?!

Answer (score 1):

I think your filePattern can only have one %d variable. If you have two, the rollover policy cannot determine the rollover frequency.

So, replace what you have now:

```
filePattern="${log-path}/%d{yyyy-MM}/demopro-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.gz">
```

with this:

```
filePattern="${log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/demopro-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.gz">
```

Comment: Now that works, but only partially. Now the archive log files are being created inside the tomcat 'bin' directory instead in a directory 'C:\Workspace\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\WorkspaceToolsapache-tomcat-7.0.42\logs' meaning that the filePattern is not interpreted properly. How do I overcome this without having to specify the archive  directory statically ?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that system property `catalina.base` points to the tomcat bin directory?

Comment: It appears so. But that doesn't happen with the active log file. The active log file shows up in the correct directory inside tomcat/log, but not the archived log files which gets archived inside tomcat/bin directory instead.

Comment: ... and yet this config works just fine..  `filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/demopro-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.gz">`.

Comment: @KuparBuhroy I am also facing the above last problem. Archive file going to "bin" and active file at correct place. Did you get any success with the above? I have a small change, I have no catalina, I don't want logs at my project / build dir. I want it at abosilute user.home where active file does go but archive/ rolling doesn't

Comment: It is possible that you are running into a bug in 2.0.2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-829 This is fixed in log4j-2.1, which will be released in a few days.

Comment: @RemkoPopma your answer has one little error: it isn't $${date:yyyy-MM}  (two dollar)but it actually is ${date:yyyy-MM} (only a single dollar icon).

Comment: I thought that with double $$, the value gets evaluated dynamically instead of only once at configuration time... I could be wrong.